# Ember.js looks for model of first data property returned from webapi controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ember.js, asp.net-web-api

Any llight anyone can shed on this problem that ive been struggling with for a few hours would be great...

I'm new to ember.js and I'm trying to load a user model into the global scope of my application in the following way:

(Setup is based on [this template](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/emberjs-template) and uses the webapi_adapter and serializer from there.)

So as far as I could tell to do this i needed to use the following:

**ApplicationController.js**

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    hasError: function () {
        var currentError = this.get("error");
        return !(currentError === '' || currentError === null);
    }.property('error'),
});
```

**User.js**

```
var attr = DS.attr;
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    email: attr('string'),
    accountId: attr('string'),
    firstName: attr('string'),
    lastName: attr('string'),
});

App.UserSerializer = DS.WebAPISerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'email',

    normalizeHash: {
        user: function (hash) {
            hash.email = hash.email;
            return hash;
        },
    }
});
```

**ApplicationRoute.js**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
    },
});
```

**UserController.cs**

```
//GET api/user
        public object GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var u = AuthenticatedUser;
            return new UserDto(u);
        }
```

**UserDto.cs**

```
public class UserDto
{
    public UserDto() { }

    public UserDto(User user)
    {
        Email = user.Email;
        FirstName = user.FirstName;
        LastName = user.LastName;
        AccountId = user.AccountId;
    }

    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string AccountId { get; set; }

}
```

the problem I'm encountering is that I get the error

```
Error while processing route: index No model was found for 'email' Error: No model was found for 'email'
```

where email is the first json property returned in the user data, i.e.:

```
{"Email":"johnsmith@test.com","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Smith","AccountId":"AccountJS"}
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

FYI:

**router.js**

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route("index", { path: "/" });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to show the user list, you can use it as reference:

App\controllers\UserListsController.js

```
App.UserListsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    error: ""
});
```

App\models\UserList.js

```
var attr = DS.attr;

App.UserList = DS.Model.extend({
    email: attr('string'),
    accountId: attr('string'),
    firstName: attr('string'),
    lastName: attr('string'),
});

App.UserListSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'email',

    //// ember-data-1.0.0-beta2 does not handle embedded data like they once did in 0.13, so we've to update individually if present
    //// once embedded is implemented in future release, we'll move this back to WebAPISerializer.
    //// see https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md for details
    extractArray: function (store, primaryType, payload) {
        var primaryTypeName = primaryType.typeKey;

        var typeName = primaryTypeName,
            type = store.modelFor(typeName);

        var data = {};
        data[typeName] = payload;
        payload = data;
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    normalizeHash: {
        userList: function (hash) {
            hash.email = hash.id;
            return hash;
        }
    }

});
```

App\routes\TodoListRoute.js, add

```
App.UserListsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('userList');
    },
});
```

App\templates_navbar.hbs, add

```
<li>
    {{#linkTo 'userLists'}}
      userList
    {{/linkTo}}
</li>
```

App\templates\userLists.hbs

```
<h2>Users</h2>

<section id="lists">
    {{#each controller}}
    <article class="todoList">
        <p>{{email}}</p>
        <p>{{firstName}}</p>
        <p>{{lastName}}</p>
    </article>
    {{/each}}
</section>
```

App\router.js, add

```
this.route("userLists", { path: "/userList" });
```

Controllers\UserListController.cs, sample:

```
public class UserListController : ApiController
{
    private TodoItemContext db = new TodoItemContext();

    // GET api/userList
    public List<UserDto> GetUserLists()
    {
        var u = new User
        {
            Email = "test@test.com",
            FirstName = "first",
            LastName = "last",
            AccountId = "1324"
        };
        List<UserDto> users = new List<Models.UserDto>();
        users.Add(new UserDto(u));
        return users;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Models\User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public User() { }

    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string AccountId { get; set; }
}


public class UserDto
{
    public UserDto() { }

    public UserDto(User user)
    {
        Email = user.Email;
        FirstName = user.FirstName;
        LastName = user.LastName;
        AccountId = user.AccountId;
    }

    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are a savior my friend!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ember.js expects your API response data to be like this:

```
{ 
    "user": {
        "Email": "johnsmith@test.com",
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Smith",
        "AccountId": "AccountJS"
    }
}
```

I don't know about the `webapi_adapter` you mention, but this is how `RESTAdapter` expects the response to be formatted: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html